# How do you configure NGINX so that it handles 50x errors from upstream server B that upstream server A cannot?

Tags: nginx

I have recently started learning NGINX and encountered some problems. I am still getting and error 500, even if I have configured NGINX (1.4.6) with an error_page directive. The config works ( I get the woops.html as expected ) if I try *not* to send error 500 from the second upstream server. Here's my configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /srv/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name test.dev;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            error_page 500 @retry;
    }

    location @retry {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            error_page 500 /woops.html;
    }

    location = /woops.html {
            root /srv/www;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen localhost:8080;
    server_name localhost;
    root /srv/www;

    location / {
            return 500;
    }
} 

server {
    listen 8081;
    listen localhost:8081;
    server_name localhost;
    root /srv/www/app;

    location / {
            return 500;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I guess, you should use `=` flag in first `error_page`. This `error_page 500 = @retry;`

Comment: Thanks. I added that flag on the first `error_page` but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Oh, you want to send `200 OK` with `woops.html` content in case of error 500? It's quite bad idea. Why you want it?

Comment: I just wanted to get the content of `woops.html` in the event that the second upstream returns `500`. ( Because I wanted to test if it can really be done according to what this book _Nginx Essentials_ (2015) is saying. )

Comment: I guess you already get it.

Comment: Well, either I'm doing something wrong ( in which case somebody can point out what else can be done ) or, yeah, that it cannot really be done ( in which case the book needs updating ).

Comment: Error code 500 still could (and will) send some html. In your config you'll get content of `woops.html` file